# Why does priority queue has default initial capacity of 11

Tags: java, priority-queue

Java docs specify 
    `Creates a PriorityQueue with the default initial capacity (11) that orders its elements according to their natural ordering.`

I was trying to understand why ? What is the advantage of 11 ?

Comment: It's a prime number, it's small enough to be trivial but large enough to be useful. Also, it prevents having to grow the queue from 1->2, 2->3, 3->4 if you want to add 1000 objects.

Comment: Well, although "The details of the growth policy are not specified", it is vanishingly unlikely to be *O(N),* and in fact "this implementation provides O(log(n)) time for the enqueing and dequeing methods."